# CSV Row and Column Reshape using Python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I'm pretty new to Python and Data Science. I have the following CSV file which looks like this:

[Original CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqqQD.png)

It has approximately 1500 columns.

I want to reshape this CSV file using Python like this:

```
[{'labels': ['A', 'B'], 'scores': [0.9959241151809692, 0.005847269669175148], 'sequence': 'A'},
 {'labels': ['B', 'A'], 'scores': [0.9949565529823303, 0.0007053299923427403], 'sequence': 'B'},
 {'labels': ['B', 'A'], 'scores': [0.9949565529823303, 0.0007053299923427403], 'sequence': 'B'},
 ...]
```

**labels**, **scores** and **sequence** should be in separate rows.

Any help on how can I do it? Tried everything I know so far, but no progress yet.

Comment: From what I see there is no difference between `what you have and what you want`.

Comment: The current output in CSV has rows as subsequent columns, like:
{'labels': ['A', 'B'], 
'scores': [0.9959241151809692, 0.005847269669175148], 
'sequence': 'A'}

But I want them in the following manner:

{'labels': ['A', 'B'], 'scores': [0.9959241151809692, 0.005847269669175148], 'sequence': 'A'}, where labels, scores and sequence are separate rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant json ? I don't really recognize a csv here, but it doesn't matter, here is what i would do :

```
output = [{},{},{}]
for row in range(len(csv_content)):
     output[0][row] = csv_content[row]["labels"]
     output[1][row] = csv_content[row]["scores"]
     output[2][row] = csv_content[row]["sequence"]
```

Comment: That could help.. That means I have to iterate the loop for 1500 times. And how can I save this updated output as a CSV?

Comment: If you want to save this as CSV, i think that the csv module can help you. I dont know how it works, so i can t really give an example

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
with open('input.csv', 'r') as fin,\
     open('output.csv', 'w') as fout:
    line_out = ''
    for i, line_in in enumerate(fin, start=1):
        line_out += line_in.rstrip()
        if not i % 3:
            fout.write(line_out + '\n')
            line_out = ''
```